# Material Design Selection List Keyboard Actions

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm totally new to accessibility technology in angular and material design. In my project I would like to have selection list where one item can be selected. This selection list should be focusable but when focused it should be able to navigate over items with keyboard up/down arrows. I know there is an example on [this site](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview) where they show how it behaves with `mat-list-option` items in `mat-selection-list`. But this solution introduce checkboxes and I need solution with menu items without checkboxes. Just select one element with keyboard and close `MatDialog`.

The main problem is with keyboard because when I try to use `mat-list` with `mat-list-item` items or `mat-nav-list` with `mat-list-item` items the keyboard arrows does not work.

The only one component that is working with keyboard is `mat-selection-list` with `mat-list-option` items but this introduce checkboxes on the right and this is not what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to design really user friendly interface but I can't because of it. Maybe the question is how to enable keyboard over those items? Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Material design list to behave like getmdl-select dropdown (respond to keyboard arrows and tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627391/how-to-set-material-design-list-to-behave-like-getmdl-select-dropdown-respond-t)